# route, anchor, function and render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm quite a noob in RubyOnRails but I would like to write the description of an object in my homepage if a parameter is written in the url.

For example :

wwW.myWebsite.com -> display the homepage

www.myWebsite.com/demos  -> display the homepage with the description field of the object demos

I have done :

-in route.rb

```
match 'demos/:id' => 'demos#display_description'
```

-in demo controller

```
def display_demo
   @demo = Demo.find_by_slug(params[:id])
end
```

but how to load the homepage (which will have to know the demo variable...) ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Create a controller for your homepage, ie. :

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @demos = Demo.all # this will load all your demos in an array, or Demo.paginate :page => params[:page] if you want pagination from will_paginate for example.
  end
end
```

in your routes, route the root to your HomeController :

```
root :to => "home#index"
```

and voila!

Read the guides from http://guides.rubyonrails.org for more info if you're a rails beginner.

Comment: Thank you but how do I describe the action to do when a person goes to mysite.com/demos/1 or mysite.com/demos/15 ?